# How do native speakers guess the pronunciation of a word that they've never seen before?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

How do native speakers guess the pronunciation of a word that they've never seen before ? Is there a general rule for that ?

For example, someone said :

```
Words that end in -ic or -tion will be stressed on the second to last syllable. It doesn't matter how many syllables long a word is, we will count backward.
Here are some examples with -ic and -tion.
-ic: `classic, fan`tas-tic, e-co-`nom-ic, en-thu-si-`as-tic
-tion: `nation, con`di-tion, in-tu-`i-tion, spec-i-fi-`ca-tion
```

I would like to know more other rules like the above one, not only how to stress the word properly but also the way to pronounce one word correctly (or nearly correct) without knowing the phonetic.

p/s : In short, my question is : "Is there a way to guess the pronunciation of a word correctly (or nearly correct) when we don't know it's phonetic code ?"

Comment: I think this is Not Constructive. Firstly, many words have multiple "valid" pronunciations. Secondly, for any given rule, there will be exceptions. OP's rule is about as bulletproof as any, but it doesn't apply to, for example, *arabic, arithmetic, catholic,* or *rhetoric*.

Comment: Often native speakers will incorrectly guess the pronunciation of a word they've only seen written down, and may go for many years until they hear with surprise the correct or accepted way.

Comment: Hi all, in short, my question is : "Is there a way to guess the pronunciation of a word correctly (or nearly correct) when we don't know it's phonetic code ?"

Comment: @JatSing, yes, it is possible. Loan word phonology deals with this issue. Of course, it involves stress patterns, phonatactics, and other phonological processes.

Comment: @RainDoctor, thanks, I am googling for "Loan word phonology" ...

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a number of Internet resources that could be consulted and I would encourage you to pursue that.

This site (for example)
http://funeasyenglish.com/american-english-pronunciation-word-and-sentence-stress.htm

has some of the "rules" I think you are after.

> Stress on the first syllable
>
> • most 2-syllable nouns – china, table, export, pencil
>
> • most 2-syllable adjectives – slender, clever, happy
>
> Stress on the last syllable
>
> • most 2-syllable verbs – to export, to decide, to begin
>
> Stress on the third syllable from the end (ante-penultimate syllable)
>
> • words ending in “cy”, “ty”, “phy” and “gy” – democracy, dependability, photography, geology, society
>
> • words ending in “al” – critical, geological

Comment: +1 Thanks, seem helpful to me. Btw, as I said, I am not only looking for the rule of stressing.